# How to Count Video playing remaining Time in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:)
                                                         name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:mPlayer.moviePlayer];


 - (void)MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
        {
            if ((mPlayer.moviePlayer.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) == MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK)
            {
                NSLog(@"content play length is %g seconds", mPlayer.moviePlayer.duration);
                timeRemain = [NSTimeIntervalSince1970 [mPlayer.moviePlayer.duration]-[mPlayer.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime]];
                NSLog(@"Time Remaining::%g",timeRemain);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am trying to get remaining time for playing video but not getting , can any1 help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPMoviePlayerController duration is in seconds already.
So

```
[mPlayer.moviePlayer.duration]-[mPlayer.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime]
```

will return the number of seconds in current time and total duration as NSTimeInterval.

Comment: yes but i want observer notification while playing video so i dont know about it. can u please tell me how to get it?

Comment: i got solution. Thanks

Comment: can you show me the solution please ?? thanks @Seema

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)updateDuration
{
    int remainingDuration = mPlayer.moviePlayer.duration - mPlayer.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime;

    if (mPlayer.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime != mPlayer.moviePlayer.duration  ) {

        [btnRemainingDuration setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video ends in %d seconds", remainingDuration] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```